# Assigned values have not the same length - Python

Tags: python, population, genetic, fitness

I am working on Genetic Algorithm, particularly finding the fitness of population. But it has the #TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()

Python suggests me a reference code:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/deap/base.py in setValues(self, values)
186 
187     def setValues(self, values):
188         assert len(values) == len(self.weights), "Assigned values have not the same length than fitness weights"                                                
189         try:
190             self.wvalues = tuple(map(mul, values, self.weights))

TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

Below is my original code to find the fitness of population. How can I correct the error by applying the suggested code?

```
fitness_set = list(tb.map(tb.evaluate, population))
for ind, fit in zip(population, fitness_set):
    ind.fitness.values = fit
```

Comment: Where do you set `self.weights` and `values`? The names and usages imply that they should be sequences, but the error indicates that at least one is a number.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that your `tb.evaluate` function returns an `int` variable instead of a `tuple` variable.

I mean if your `tb.evaluate` function executes something like `return 123` in the end, you should change it to `return 123,`.

This makes the function return a `tuple` rather then an `int`.

Returning a `tuple` variable can solve the problem you encountered because `len((123,))` is equal to 1.

`len((123,))` doesn't raise an `object of type 'int' has no len()` error.

Answer (score 0):

```
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

Means that you are using the function `len` that is used to get the length of a sequence, on an integral number, this makes no sense so the program fails.

To fix this `ind.fitness.values` should be a list rather than an integer.